# Symfony 2 Cache warmup

Tags: php, ant, symfony

Is there anyway to run a cache warmup replacing the location in the cache paths created with a custom one..

for eg after running

```
php console cache:warmup *..other args..*
```

i get something like

```
/home/user/code/xxx/...
```

and i want to replace it with

```
/var/www/code/xxx/....
```

here is the task i made for ant

```
<target name="warmup-cache">
  <exec dir="${basedir}"
    executable="php"
    failonerror="true">
    <arg line="app/console cache:warmup -a=name --env=prod "/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

i am using apache ant to execute this command during build

now the cache generated has all routes as /home/user/code/xxx/...

and i want to rename all that cache data to /var/www/code/...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [propertyregex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task from ant-conrib tasks.

If you could provide a more accurate example I could write the regex for you :)

Comment: thanks [FailedDev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/880096/faileddev)  . I am still reading its documentation. But surely will ask for help if stuck ..thanks